# Java - Adding another String value to existing HashMap Key without overwriting?

Tags: java, hashmap

I was wondering if someone would be able to help with regards to adding another `String` value to an existing key within a `HashMap` in Java?

I understand that you can add a Key-Value pair using the `this.put("String", "String")` method. However, it overwrites the existing value, whereas I would like multiple values stored and paired, with the same key?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Write your own custom class where the String will be your instance variable, and override the equals and the hashcode method and use it, in your way
My question is, why do you want to do this?

Comment: "*adding another String value to an existing key within a HashMap in Java*" it is not very clear. What should be result of `map.put("foo","bar"); map.put("foo","bar")`? What should be value of `foo` key? Should it be `"barbar"` or something like list `"[bar, bar]"` or maybe you want to have only unique values so it should still be only `"bar"`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What are you hoping to achieve here?

A `Map` (the `HashMap`) in your case is a direct "mapping" from one "key" to another value.

E.g.

```
"foo" -> 123
"bar" -> 321
"far" -> 12345
"boo" -> 54321
```

This means that if you were to try:

```
myHashMap.get("foo");
```

It would return the value `123` (of course, the type of the value you return can be anything you want).

Of course, this also means that any changes you make to the value of the key, it overrides the original value you assigned it, just like changing the value of a variable will override the original one assigned.

Say:

```
myHashMap.put("foo", 42);
```

The old value of `"foo"` in the map would be replaced with `42`. So it would become:

```
"foo" -> 42
"bar" -> 321
"far" -> 12345
"boo" -> 54321
```

However, if you need multiple `String` objects that are mapped from a single key, you could use a different object which can store multiple objects, such as an Array or a List (or even another `HashMap` if you wanted.

For example, if you were to be using `ArrayLists`, when you are assigning a value to the `HashMap`, (say it is called `myHashMap`), you would first check if the key has been used before, if it hasn't, then you create a new `ArrayList` with the value you want to add, if it has, then you just add the value to the list.

(Assume `key` and `value` have the values you want)

```
ArrayList<String> list;
if(myHashMap.containsKey(key)){
    // if the key has already been used,
    // we'll just grab the array list and add the value to it
    list = myHashMap.get(key);
    list.add(value);
} else {
    // if the key hasn't been used yet,
    // we'll create a new ArrayList<String> object, add the value
    // and put it in the array list with the new key
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(value);
    myHashMap.put(key, list);
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You can do like this!

```
Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
.
.
if(map.containsKey(key)){
    map.get(key).add(value);
} else {
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
   list.add(value);
   map.put(key, list);
}
```

**Or** you can do the same thing by one line code in Java 8 style .

```
map.computeIfAbsent(key, k ->new ArrayList<>()).add(value);
```

Comment: The 1st  method will not work in all cases. you are not assigning the updated value back to map.

Answer (score 5):

Would you like a concatenation of the two strings?

```
map.put(key, val);
if (map.containsKey(key)) {
    map.put(key, map.get(key) + newVal);
}
```

Or would you like a list of all the values for that key?

```
HashMap<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
String key = "key";
String val = "val";
String newVal = "newVal";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(val);
map.put(key, list);
if (map.containsKey(key)) {
    map.get(key).add(newVal);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As others pointed, `Map` by specification can have only one value for a given key. You have 2 solutions:

- Use `HashMap<String, List<String>>` to store the data
- Use [Multimap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) which is provided by 3rd party Google Collections lib

Answer (score 1):

As described in [Map interface documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) Map contains a set of keys, so it is not capable of containing multiple non-unique keys.

I suggest you to use lists as values for this map.

Answer (score 0):

Store value as list under map So if key is test and there are two values say val1 and val2 then key will be test and value will be list containing val1 and val2

But if your intention is to have two separate entries for same key, then this is not Map is designed for. Think if you do map.get("key"), which value you expects

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Map<String, Collection<String>>` but adding and removing values would be cumbersome . Better way is using guava [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) - a container that allows storing multiple values for each key.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly store multiple values under a single key, but the value associated with a key can be any type of object, such as an ArrayList, which will hold multiple values.  For example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class HashMapList {
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> strings = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

    public void add(String key, String value) {
        ArrayList<String> values = strings.get(key);
        if (values == null) {
            values = new ArrayList<String>();
            strings.put(key, values);
        }

        values.add(value);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> get(String key) {
        return strings.get(key);
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        HashMapList mymap = new HashMapList();

        mymap.add("key", "value1");
        mymap.add("key", "value2");

        ArrayList<String> values = mymap.get("key");
        for (String value : values) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

it's impossible,because String is immutable if you use the String as the key of map the same key's value has the same hashcode value.

Comment: It's the key that gets hashed, not the value.