# Populating Map values with multiple parameters from nativeQuery

Tags: java, collections, entitymanager

Out of curiosity, I was wondering if it would be possible to populate a `Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>>` with my query's result...

I have the following query:

```sql
 SELECT DISTINCT code, email FROM user;
```

That results on multiple email records for the same code, as such:

```
| CODE     | EMAIL                     |
| -------- | --------                  |
| 1        | person@email.com          |
| 1        | otherPerson@email.com     |
| 2        | someOtherPerson@email.com |
```

And the method (that should return something):

```java
    @Override
    public Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> returnCodeEmail() {
        StringBuilder sql = "SELECT DISTINCT code, email FROM user";
        return new HashMap();
    }
```

I tried:

```java
 return (Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>>) entityManager
       .createNativeQuery(sql.toString())
       .getResultList()
       .stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(
             t -> ((Tuple) t).get(0), 
             t -> ((Tuple) t).get(1)
        ));
```

But it doesn't seem to be able to populate the list as intended...

How can I make sure my map has a Key that is the `code` and a value list of  `emails` as in the table?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should define entity classes for the user and email, and use a standard HQL approach.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717234/java-adding-another-string-value-to-existing-hashmap-key-without-overwriting) post from awhile back!

So, simply put... a Tuple structure can work really well or such queries, and the return object is really easy to manage.

Then its just a matter of filtering out the values and the key they're associated with, adding the values to the Map their key is in it already, and adding the key to the list if its not.

The code:

```
   List<Tuple> result = query.getResultList();
   Map<Integer, List<String>> finalObject = new HashMap<>();
   List<String> emailsValue;
   BigInteger codeKey;

   for (Tuple t : result) {
       if (t.get("id", BigInteger.class) != null) {
           codeKey = t.get("id", BigInteger.class);
           if (finalObject.containsKey(codeKey.intValue())) {
               emailsValue = finalObject.get(codeKey.intValue());
               emailsValue.add(t.get("email", String.class));
       } else {
           emailsValue = new ArrayList<>();
           emailsValue.add(t.get("email", String.class));
           finalObject.put(codeKey.intValue(), emailsValue);
       }
   }
```